# Jmeter : How to upload dynamic excel file which has different data and load test with Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-3.2

I have an excel upload functionality in my web application which uploads users to the system. I need to load test this with more than 100 users. And all of these 100 users will be uploading different excel file with different user data.

If I configure load with the same excel file, the application will throw error since the values get duplicated in the application. For example If the thread 1 excel is having name as name : sam and value : 1, and if the same excel is again getting uploaded, the application already has the user sam in it and throws 400 bad request.

Is there a way to load test the excel upload in realistic scenario but with different excel and dynamic values in it?

Answer (score 1):

You can parameterize the file name/path normally using i.e. [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)  or even better [Directory Listing Config](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/introducing-directory-listing-config-plugin-jmeter/) so each virtual user would have its own Excel file for uploading.

[image]

And then in [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler just use the variable from the CSV Data Set Config or Directory Listing Config

[image]